# How to get previous date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying out a code where I get a mail with specific subject line -
"Your daily habit tracker"+previous day's date;

While I figured out how to publish today's date - I am just not able to understand how I can publish yesterday's date instead.
Attaching code, please help thank you!

```
var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MMMM");
```

```js
function sendFormEmail() {
    var toEmailAddress = "1@mailinator.com";
    var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MMMM");
    var htmlMessage = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Habit tracker form.html").getContent();
    var subject = "Daily keystone habit tracker";
    var message = "Some message";
    Logger.log(now);
    // MailApp.sendEmail(toEmailAddress, subject, message, {
    //   name: 'Future Mac',
    //   htmlBody: htmlMessage
    // });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

let Yesterday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() -1);